# jQuery not returning any value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that checks if the contents of the form is valid. checkEmpty, checkNumeric and checkEmail is working fine if i comment out the checkFile function. But if I include checkFile, it breaks the code causing the function not to return any value.

Here is the checkFile function. It's supposed to check the file extension.

```
$.fn.checkFile = function(fileValue) {

    //var fileName = contactform.cv.value;
    var extension = fileValue.substring(fileValue.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    alert(extension);
    if(extension === 'jpg' || extension === 'jpeg' ||extension === 'docx' ||extension === 'pdf' ||extension === 'xlsx'){
        alert("correct extension");
        return true;
    }else{
        alert("incorrect extension");
        return false;
    }

};
```

Also the function should be working fine. I tried it seperately to see if it gets the extension properly.

Here is the whole code in case its needed

```
$(window).load(function() { 


// validations
$.fn.checkEmpty = function(emp) {

    if(emp === ""){
        alert("field is empty");
        return false;
    }else{
        alert("not empty");
        return true;
    }
};

$.fn.checkEmail = function(email) {

var regex = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);

    if(regex.test(email)){
        alert("mail is valid");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("mail is invalid");
        return false;
    }
};

$.fn.checkNumeric = function(value) {

    // 10 digits for phone number ?
    /*
    if (value.length !== 10 || value === "" || !$.isNumeric(value)) {
        alert("not a numerical value");
    } else {
        alert("numerical value");
    }*/

    var regex =new RegExp(/^(?:\d*\,\d*|\d+)$/);

    if(regex.test(value) && value!==""){
        alert("numerical value");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("not numerical value");
        return false;
    }

};

$.fn.checkFile = function(fileValue) {

    //var fileName = contactform.cv.value;
    var extension = fileValue.substring(fileValue.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    alert(extension);
    if(extension === 'jpg' || extension === 'jpeg' ||extension === 'docx' ||extension === 'pdf' ||extension === 'xlsx'){
        alert("correct extension");
        return true;
    }else{
        alert("incorrect extension");
        return false;
    }

};

$.fn.checkField = function() {

    var empty = "empty";
    var numeric = "numeric";
    var email = "email";
    var file = "file";
    var flag=0;
    var retval;

    $("input:text").each(function() {

        var required = $(this).data("reqs");

        if(required.toLowerCase().indexOf(empty) !== -1){
            retval = $(this).checkEmpty($(this).val());
            if(retval === false){
                flag++;
                $(this).after('<span style="color:red">*</span>');
            }
        }
        if (required.toLowerCase().indexOf(numeric) !== -1){
            retval = $(this).checkNumeric($(this).val());
            if(retval === false){
                flag++;
                $(this).after('<span style="color:red">*</span>');
            }
        }
        if(required.toLowerCase().indexOf(email) !== -1){
            retval = $(this).checkEmail($(this).val());
            if(retval === false){
                flag++;
                $(this).after('<span style="color:red">*</span>');
            }
        }
    });
    $("input:file").each(function() {
        if(required.toLowerCase().indexOf(file) !== -1){
            retval = $(this).checkFile($(this).val());
            if(retval === false){
                flag++;
                $(this).after('<span style="color:red">*</span>');
            }
        }

    });

    alert(flag);
    return (flag > 0) ? false : true;

};
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: These functions make absolutely no sense on the jQuery prototype. And why do you create them `onload`?

Comment: Its logic is correct and working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Dgpcx/1/

Comment: What code does return nothing any more? Do you see any exceptions in the console?

Comment: this is my first try on jquery so any comment on the not making any sense part is welcome.
it does not alert the flag on the last 2 lines also should not submit the form but it does so it wont return false.

also no exceptions in the console

Comment: try adding a `return false;` at the end of `checkFile` and wrap everything inside a try catch + `console.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bergi pointed it out, it doesn't make much sense to add the function to the prototype if you pass it the filename as a parameter...

However, adding it to the prototype can be a good idea if you actually use `this` within the method:

```
$.fn.checkFile = function(){
    var filename = $(this).val();
    if (/(?:jpe?g|docx|pdf|xlsx)$/.test(filename)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};
```

You can test this method at http://jsfiddle.net/NVvzN/. Try choosing different files from your computer to see how it works.

---

PS: my guess is, if you accept .docx and .xlsx, you should also accept .doc and .xls; in that case, the regular expression would be `/(?:jpe?g|docx?|pdf|xlsx?)$/`